# ::after content font-family only showing correctly on IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, pseudo-element

This is what I have: http://agents.jeneth.com/versions/new/

The `<div class="hr"></div>` looks perfect in IE, but the decorative font for the 'e' in the center of the line doesn't look so decorative in any other browser. It's just an 'e'.

Here's a codepen with the code: http://codepen.io/carolemagouirk/pen/ElxnD

I was trying to find an easy way to make a nice horizontal rule without a bunch of code. I read that `<hr>` is treated wildly different by different browsers so, I decided to go with a `div`.

I hope I'm missing something obvious and easy to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you defined something like this..

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'nymphetteregular';
    src: url('Nymphette-webfont.eot');
    src: url('Nymphette-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('Nymphette-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('Nymphette-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('Nymphette-webfont.svg#nymphetteregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Here, I have defined it as `nymphetteregular` after this declaration, then one can use this in css as a font..

make sure your website have source of the files .. if you don't have one.. you may find it [here](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Nymphette).
Note: I am not sure if its allowed to use commercially. Please verify if not using personally.

I am sure this will solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't think that font is allowed for commercial use, either, so I went with something else which does use the format you've outlined.

Answer (score 0):

declare your @font face rules first before you use them

Comment: Turns out it was the font I was using. Where I declared my @font-face in the css made no difference.